# Using FedEx return envelopes at the French Consulate in Boston ($38 vs ~$10)

Tags: schengen, passports, paperwork, vfs-global

The website says it is mandatory to use the consulate's/VFS's courier service ($38.50) but the helpline said it is okay to get your own envelopes (probably under $15).

I am wondering if anyone has used their own envelopes and if it is safe to do so from a possible passport loss point-of-view.

Comment: Is that for a visa?

Comment: Whether using one's own envelope is "safe" is unanswerable opinion, and depends on your personal risk tolerance. I'll guess that the French Consulate prefers FedEx envelopes because FedEx envelopes are large and tracked and well-marked, and thus less likely to go astray. They are therefore less likely to generate "Where is my passport?" complaints and reports of loss from applicants. Fewer complaints means less Consulate staff time, too.